# How can I do a good design for this model?

Tags: c#, oop, uml

I'm a beginner creating diagram classes. The necessity obligates me to do a good model.

The solution is for a math quiz. The system must generate each problem and check the answer.

I'm going to show my general classes:

Here there is the casses

```
interface IProblemFactory<T> where T : Problem<T>
{
    T Create();
}

public class ArithmeticProblemFactory : IProblemFactory<Arithmetic>
{
    // This generates Arithmetic problems
    public Arithmetic Create() { }
}

// And the others types of problems
```

Then I've got the classes which contain the problem:

```
public abstract class Problem<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
    public abstract int ResultCount { get; }
    public abstract bool CheckTheAnswer();
    protected abstract bool CheckTheAnswer(params object[] results);
    public abstract bool Equals(T other);
}

public class Arithmetic : Problem<Arithmetic>
{
    public decimal Number1 { get; set; }

    public Operations Operation { get; set; }

    public decimal Number2 { get; set; }

    public override int ResultCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    protected override bool CheckTheAnswer(params object[] results)
    {
        if (results.Length != ResultCount)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only expected " + ResultCount + " arguments.");

        decimal result = (decimal)results[0];

        switch (Operation)
        {
            case Operations.Addition:
                return Number1 + Number2 == result;
            case Operations.Subtraction:
                return Number1 - Number2 == result;
            case Operations.Multiplication:
                return Number1 * Number2 == result;
            case Operations.Division:
                return Number1 / Number2 == result;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Operator unexpected");
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(Arithmetic other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.Number1 == other.Number1 && Number2 == other.Number2;
    }
}
```

The problem I think I'm not doing a good design. Because all the problems will contain a CheckTheAnswer(params obj..). But all problems have different results.

For example in Arithmetic is neccesary only a decimal value, in comparison 2 I need to store two values, others I need to store the result like Fraction class.

Maybe I need to separate them.. Arithmetic might contain only two properties: a problem and answer but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why does `IProblem<T>` have both `CheckTheAnswer()` and `CheckTheAnswer(params object[] result)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doubt about how to organize my classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977575/doubt-about-how-to-organize-my-classes)

Comment: @Ken Well CheckTheAnswer(params object[] result) is a private function which will return a boolean value, but you have to enter all the values.

And CheckTheAnswer() will return the value from the another function. And sorry this would be a property, not a function. And this property return value without enter the values.

Comment: Looks like over engineering to me.

Comment: I said this because later, I need to cast each one of these problems to upload the answers in an database and I'd use a large switch case to convert the problem in a particular one.

For that reason, I think is necessary to do a good design

Comment: @oscar coming up with the "perfect model" for your question is quite literally the so-called "[expression problem](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/expression/expression.txt)" which does not really have a perfect solution in C#. However you can find a few very good options in this document ([PDF](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/indices/a-tree/t/Torgersen:Mads.html) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the possible Problems have a different set of results, then what functionality are you hoping to refactor out into an interface? They don't *have* any common functionality. This is your problem. You *might* be able to do something simple, like

```
interface Problem {
    void OutputProblem(OutputStream stream);
    void AcceptAnswer(InputStream stream);
    bool IsAnswerCorrect();
}
```

However, your current architecture is simply unfit for purpose.

Comment: I know but, all will have a Create function will generate a problem, another that check the answer, and the problem. Well I think so..

In fact, I was thinking in create something like a list of results to do this more common

Comment: @oscar.fimbres: You mean a Create function, like `new`? They don't have enough common logic to do anything more generic than this.